# Error in python script using selenium driver on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Case 1

I am getting below error when I try to execute simple python script using selenium driver.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I run this script , my Chrome gets opened and I get below exception and program stops there itself

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Note: I have installed chrome driver ,

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\pip>pip install chromedriver
Requirement already satisfied: chromedriver in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site
-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute the simple python script using selenium driver you need to consider a couple of things as follows :

- While initializing the `webdriver` instance you don't need to pass the `chrome` binary location. But you have to pass the location of `chromedriver` binary which can be downloaded from this [`link`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and passed as an argument as follows :

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")
  ```
- Instead of using `driver.close()` always use `driver.quit()` which will destroy both the `webdriver` and the `Web Browser` instance as follows :

  ```
  self.driver.quit()
  ```